# Azure Service Fabric vs Azure Service Fabric Mesh

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-service-fabric-mesh

After painstakingly trying to learn and try out Azure Service Fabric, I now see 'Azure Service Fabric Mesh'.
Struggling to identify the key differences.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-terminology) states 'Service Fabric is the orchestrator that powers Service Fabric Mesh'. I am aware of the services that I can deploy to a SF cluster.

How is SF Mesh any different? Maybe just SF with additional focus on containerized apps?

Answer (score 1):

Think about SF Mesh as the **serverless** Service Fabric platform (you don't have do do any cluster / VM management). It instead lets you completely focus on the application.

Read more about it here: [What is Service Fabric Mesh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-overview)

Comment: Ooops..eine ganze technische Dokument über SF Mesh auf Deutsch....hmm...Zuerst auf Englisch danach besser zu vestehen auf Deutsch 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-overview

Comment: Sorry, I have auto translate so I thought it was the english link. Fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

Service Fabric Mesh in my opinion is really another product compared to "just" Service Fabric. This is largely due the fact that Service Fabric gives you a set of programming models like the [actor model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction) and [reliable services model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction) for both statefull and stateless services. Service Fabric mesh does not offer these models! So that is the first fundamental choice you need to make.

Also, Service Fabric is a PaaS offering but you can also host it on-premises or in other cloud environments. Something you cannot do with Service Fabric Mesh.